# how to get proper dropdown format for dates

Tags: php, html, forms

following is my code for accepting date in a form:

```
$month_array = array( "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

echo "<select name='Resolved_date1' style='color:black; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color:beige;'>";
$i = 1;
while ( $i <= 31 ) {
echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
$i++;
}

echo "</select>";

echo "<select name='Resolved_date2' style='color:black; font-family: Verdana; font- weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color:beige;'>";
$i = 0;
while ( $i <= 11 ) {
echo "<option value=".$i." name='Resolved_date2'>".$month_array[$i]."</option>";      
$i++;
}
echo "</select>";
echo $_POST['Resolved_date2'];
echo "<select name='Resolved_date3' style='color:black; font-family: Verdana; font-    weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color:beige;'>";
$i = 2013;
while ( $i <= 2050 ) {    
echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";    
$i++;
}
echo "</select>";
echo $_POST['Resolved_date3'];
?>
```

the problem is that the following statement prints the month number and not the month name:
    echo $_POST['Resolved_date2'];
is there any way to resolve this? also how can we customise number of days according to months..ike if i select january i get 31 days n the dropdown and when i select june i get only 30 days in the dropdown? please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POSTed information is the value of the option, not its text. If you want the text, you can:

```
echo "<option value=".$month_array[$i]." name='Resolved_date2'>".$month_array[$i]."</option>";
```

To limit the number of days according to the chosen month, you'll have to do it on the client side, using javascript or preferably one of its frameworks like jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know month name then use this:

```
// first option
"<option value=" . $month_array[$i] 
    . " name='Resolved_date2'>" . $month_array[$i] . "</option>";

// second option
echo $month_array[$_POST['Resolved_date2']];
```

For proper days count use this:

```
$num_of_days = date('t', /*you month here*/);
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $num_of_days)
    // your code
```

**Edit:** get count of days, a little harder.

```
// first - we nned to get year
$year = date('Y'); // or as string 2013, 2012 or 2010
// now we form a string that represents the first day of a month
$first_day = '1 ' . $month_array[$i] . ' ' . $year;
// now convert it to Unix timestamp
$first_day = strtotime($first_day);
// and finally:
$num_of_days = date('t', $first_day);
// check:
echo $num_of_days
```

Comment: thanks! this worked! do we do the same thing if we wanna store the value of the month in a database? do we write  $month_array[$_POST['Resolved_date2']]; in the insert statement?

Comment: If you want to store month name in database - then yes, use `$month_array[$_POST['Resolved_date2']]`

Comment: ok..but the second part is not working, it gives the following error:date() expects parameter 2 to be long,

Comment: Edited my post, check it out

Comment: What's the value of `$first_day` after using `strtotime`?

Comment: its blank..no value  is being displayed

Comment: is there any other way? like some kind of validation, using if..?

Comment: What's the value of `$first_day` before using `strtotime`?

Answer (score 0):

And to solve your other problem alter it like this:

$month_array[] = array(
'name' => "January", 'days' => 31,
); 
and do the rest for the rest of the months.

that way u'll get array with associative arrays so getting $month_array[0]['name'] will give January and $month_array[0]['days'] will contain the number of the days 31.

Comment: I noticed... post edited shortly after. I hope at least I provided some laughter for someone XD